# Android: Setting up In-app billing for opening a new activity class

Tags: android, android-activity, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I have read the in-app billing setup but still I don't understand a thing..

Can anyone or does anyone have a sample in-app billing of opening an activity?

Example:
I have a game that has five buttons and all of the buttons open a new java class activity.
But in one of the buttons I want to add in-app billing that a user has to purchase only once first before viewing the activity.

Thanks

Wally

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to check out an abstraction layer like [Swarm](http://swarmconnect.com/virtual_store), which provides in-app purchases with some convenience wrappers.  You can do things like (pseudocode):

`userInventory.containsItem(itemId)`
and
`storeItem.purchase()`

Which should make the majority of in-app purchase stuff pretty simple.

Comment: So where abouts do I add this line of code?

Do I add it in the button? and where it says itemId do I replace it with the name of the item name I've given it?